# Fixed header not working when scrolling in IE6

Tags: jquery, scroll, internet-explorer-6

I want the header of a page to be of fixed positioned when a user scrolls to a certain point in the page.

This functions correctly in all browsers bar IE6 :(

View the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vZBSg/4/

Comment: The http://perldoc.perl.org site has a header which does exactly what you're attempting.  It works great in everything but... IE6. (In IE6 it displays a lovely "...your browser's old and doesn't support modern websites..." message to users.) Best of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position:fixed was not implemented in IE6. There is a CSS only workaround http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/

Comment: I sort of tried that but it didn't seem to work.  Will take a proper look tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Well kind of jerky but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/vZBSg/5/

Comment: I use it all the time now.  Much easier to demo problems etc.  Would love to see some sort of intellisense implemented :)